# How to color some strings in a file

Tags: bash, colors

I prepare a file Hello.txt as follows.

```
1253125213
213532135
23513125215
```

Then, I want to color each line blue except "2", and color the "2" red.

At first, I wrote

```
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
```

and tried to do `sed 's/2/${RED}2${BLUE}/'`, but this isn't work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, double quotes are required for interpolation:

```
$ sed "s/2/${RED}2${BLUE}/" Hello.txt
1233[0;31m2233[0;34m53125213
233[0;31m2233[0;34m13532135
233[0;31m2233[0;34m3513125215
```

However, the ASCII escape sequences contain characters that affect sed, so you have to convert the escape character sequence into the actual control characters. This can be done through the use of a subshell. Note the final `/g`, meaning that multiple replacements are allowed per line.

```
$ sed "s/2/`echo $RED`2`echo $BLUE`/g" Hello.txt
```

[image: coloured output 1]

Now, this still isn't quite right. What we really should be doing is setting each line to start blue, and then making each `2` replacement start red and end blue. The hat character, `^`, is a Regular Expression meaning the start of a line. Also note the pipes and rearrangement to use `cat`.

```
$ cat Hello.txt | sed "s/^/`echo $BLUE`/" | sed "s/2/`echo $RED`2`echo $BLUE`/g"
```

[image: coloured output 2]

You can also make it cleaner by moving the subshell conversion to your variable assignment. Curly brackets are required for `RED` so as to distinguish it from the `2` character so that it doesn't try to use the non-existent variable `RED2`.

```
$ BLUE=`echo '\033[0;34m'`
$ RED=`echo '\033[0;31m'`
$ cat Hello.txt | sed "s/^/$BLUE/" | sed "s/2/${RED}2${BLUE}/g"
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by ZimbiX, use double quotes et cetera.

An alternative to his method is to use the `$'…'` syntax where escape sequences are interpreted. I.e.:

```
\e    => ASCII ESC (0x1b, 033)
\033  => ASCII ESC (0x1b, 033)
\x1b  => ASCII ESC (0x1b, 033)
```

So:

```
red=$'\e[31m'
blue=$'\e[34m'
```

Then:

```
printf $blue && sed "s/2/${red}2$blue/g" Hello.txt
```

Or, if you want, include a *reset* variable:

```
cc=$'\e[0m'
printf $blue && sed "s/2/$cc${red}2$cc$blue/g" Hello.txt && printf $cc
```

To view the code say something like:

```
(printf $blue && sed "s/2/${red}2$blue/g" Hello.txt) | cat -v
```

Also note the use of `g` for global in `sed`.